# Why doesn't my simple the_title filter get applied?

Tags: plugin-development, title, filters

I have added the code below to an active plugin, but it's having no effect on my posts.

```
add_filter( ‘the_title’, ‘myfunction’);

function myfunction($title) {
 return "Why won't this work?" . $title;
}
```

What am I missing here?

The post templates are definitely using the_title(), and the theme is normal (wp_head(), etc), and there are no conditionals surrounding the function in the plugin that would make it not run.  I have also tried adding different priority in the add_filter function, from -9999 to 9999, to no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
add_filter( ‘the_title’, ‘myfunction’);
```

to this:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'myfunction' );
```

(If this is indeed your problem it is likely an issue of copy/pasting code from a tutorial with curly quotes in place of standard single-quote marks.)

p.s. prefix your function name with your Plugin slug. "`myfunction`" is far too generic.

Comment: Curly quotes was it! I was going mad trying to figure that out.

Comment: (Oh, and myfunction isn't the real function name.)